# Advantages of Particle Swarm Optimization over Bayesian Optimization for hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization, optunity

There's substantial contemporary research on [Bayesian Optimization](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/nando.defreitas/publications/BayesOptLoop.pdf) (1) for tuning ML hyperparameters. The driving motivation here is that a minimal number of data points are required to make informed choices about what points are worthwhile to try (objective function calls are expensive, so making fewer is better) because training a model is time-intensive -- some modestly-large SVM problems that I've worked on can take between minutes and hours to complete.

On the other hand, [Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a particle swarm implementation to address  for the same task. I'm not overwhelmingly familiar with PSO, but it seems like it must be less efficient in the sense of requiring a larger number of trial points, and therefore objective function evaluations, to assess the hyperparameter surface.

Am I missing a key detail that makes PSO preferred to BO in the machine learning context? Or is the choice between the two always inherently contextual for the hyperparameter tuning task?

---

(1) Shahriari et al, "Taking the Human out of the Loop: A Review of Bayesian Optimizaiton."

Comment: doesn't need gradient.  works with discontinuity.  moderately efficient.  handles several dimensions.  handles noise well.  Has built-in robustness of estimator.

Comment: @EngrStudent You can say all of those things about BO, except BO appears to be **more efficient** because it requires a smaller number of function evaluation, at least in my reckoning. I'm not asking about PSO in general, I'm asking about its merits relative to BO.

Comment: They might be related.  I wonder if PSO is a heuristic approximation of BO.    I don't know BO at all.  With other Bayes methods you need a non-informative prior but without ephemeris that usually comes from 10k+ samples and Metropolis-Hastings.  In that sort of comparison PSO might be competitive.

Comment: PSO is consistent with "Algorithm 1" in your reference with the caveat that it is an ensemble, and that selection of the maximum per particle is weighted with previous position of the particle and its pseudo-momentum.

Comment: Not well enough educated on the topic to make this a definitive answer, but I would think Bayesian Optimization should suffer the same fate as most efficient optimizers with highly multi-modal problems (see: 95% of machine learning problems): it zeros in on the closest local minimum without "surveying" the global space. I think Particle Swarm would have better luck finding non-local minimums.

Comment: @CliffAB I haven't observed that in my trials. Beyond my personal uses, BO is also used for precisely these ML hyperparameter tuning problems. Some versions of BO use overly-greedy acquisition functions so the nominally global optimizer tends to revert to a local optimizer. But better acquisition functions will inherently trade off between exploitation and exploration in a way that can provably have zero cumulative regret!

Comment: Right. I think it would be very problem-dependent: if the hyper-parameter space is uni-modal, has a hyper-plane of equivalence, or a very large domain of attraction to the global minimum, then I can't think of a reason for particle swarm outside of ease of implementation (which definitively could be the real answer for its popularity). However, for problems that are highly multi-modal, I could see utility in the particle swarm.

Comment: Apologies for my late arrival to the party, not sure how I managed to overlook a question about Optunity for so long! :-)

Comment: @MarcClaesen I must admit, I was hoping that you would find the time to reply at some point. Late or not, I think we're all glad that you have arrived.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the lead developer of Optunity I'll add my two cents.

We have done extensive benchmarks comparing Optunity with the most popular Bayesian solvers (e.g., hyperopt, SMAC, bayesopt) on real-world problems, and the results indicate that PSO is in fact not less efficient in many practical cases. In our benchmark, which consists of tuning SVM classifiers on various datasets, Optunity is actually more efficient than hyperopt and SMAC, but slightly less efficient than BayesOpt. I would love to share the results here, but I'm going to wait until Optunity is *finally* published in JMLR (under review for over a year now, so don't hold your breath ...).

As you indicate, increased efficiency is a commonly used selling point for Bayesian optimization, but in practice it only holds water if the assumptions of the underlying surrogate models hold, which is far from trivial. In our experiments, Optunity's very simple PSO solver is often competitive with complex Bayesian approaches in terms of number of function evaluations. Bayesian solvers work very well when provided with good priors, but with an uninformative prior there is virtually no structural benefit over metaheuristic methods like PSO in terms of efficiency.

A big selling point for PSO is the fact it's embarassingly parallel. Bayesian optimization is often hard to parallelize, due to its inherently sequential nature (hyperopt's implementation being the only real exception). Given opportunities to distribute, which is becoming the norm, Optunity quickly takes the lead in wall-clock time to obtain good solutions.

Another key difference between Optunity and most other dedicated hyperparameter optimization libraries is the target audience: Optunity has the simplest interface and is targetted towards non-machine learning experts, whereas most other libraries require some understanding of Bayesian optimization to use effectively (i.e., they are targetted towards specialists).

The reason we made the library is that despite the fact dedicated hyperparameter optimization methods exist, they lack adoption in practice. Most people are still either not tuning at all, doing it manually, or via naive approaches like grid or random search. In our opinion, a key reason for this is the fact that existing libraries prior to developing Optunity were too difficult to use in terms of installation, documentation, API and often limited to a single environment.

Comment: As informed an answer as we could get! I'm curious: you say PSO solver is competitive with Bayesian Optimization approaches. Is that to say that PSO *run in parallel* is found to be faster than Bayseian Optimization *run sequentially*? Not trying to be mean, but it's an important distinction for me to understand.

Comment: Nope, both running sequentially. In our experiments (tuning SVMs), the efficiency of PSO and Bayesian optimization is competitive in terms of number of function evaluations. We didn't compare efficiency in terms of wall-clock time in distributed settings as that would be a bit of a cheap shot since many Bayesian optimization methods simply can't do that.

Comment: That's interesting. Any thoughts as to why? Unstable hyper-parameter surface?

Comment: I think there are several reasons. For one, hyperparameter surfaces have a lot of local optima (e.g., due to finite sample effects, cross-validation folds, inherent randomness in some learning approaches). Secondly, Bayesian optimization relies on building accurate surrogate objective functions, which is not an easy task until the objective function has been sampled plenty of times. Bayesian optimization takes a while before convergence speeds up (an often omitted detail). By that time metaheuristic methods like PSO have reached their local search phase too. PSO is *very* good at local search.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know enough about Bayesian Optimization to know how well it handles lots of noise in the response space: since many ML techniques, even conditional on the fixed set of tuning parameters, don't really find a global min, I wonder if this "optimization noise" is more detrimental to BO than to PSO; i.e. if you can only calculate $f(x) + \epsilon$ rather than $f(x)$, it's *much* harder to get a reasonable estimate of the derivative from finite differences, for example. Here $\epsilon$ is the error associated with failing to find the global minimum.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. I've built my own BO software, which I must admit is mostly a vanity project at this point, so I understand how the BO procedure works in some detail; I'm glad that I can start to scratch the surface of what else is going on the hyperparameter tuning world. Your remark about naive approaches really hits home with me, as one of my older naive tuning programs has been tuning a model for a week now with no end in sight... Thanks for your contribution, and I'm sure I'll have more questions once I digest this.

Comment: (+1) This is quite surprising. How many function evaluations did you use in your benchmark? (ballpark)
Do any of the BO algorithms that you compared implement: (a) full marginalization of hyper-parameters; (b) input and output warping; (c) a portfolio of acquisition functions and/or (c2) predictive entropy search (PES)? A key aspect for BO to work is to take into account uncertainty properly, especially in early stages, via full marginalization. Also, warping can help with nonstationarity (which is a big problem for traditional BO), and "simple" acquisition functions can be too greedy.

Comment: I agree that naive (and also many not-so-naive) implementations of BO can have all sorts of problems and require a lot of fiddling, but I still wonder how PSO would perform against the state of the art of BO. (Of course, with the caveat that BO would be *much* more computationally expensive, and with all the problems that you mentioned.)

Comment: @lacerbi We compared with state-of-the-art hyperparameter optimization libraries that use Bayesian techniques uner the hood (hyperopt, bayesopt and SMAC).

Comment: @Marc: Thanks. However, I asked specifically for the presence of some features that substantially affect the efficiency of BO. I find quite hard to believe that state-of-the-art BO is beaten by PSO in terms of serial efficiency. I may agree that PSO beats BO in terms of usability, parallelization or other properties you mentioned, and that would be good enough for your goal -- I am just wondering about raw efficiency here (which I understand it is not what the OP asked, it's for my personal understanding).

Comment: @Marc: I don't know these libraries in detail, but a quick look at the user reference suggests that none of these libraries implement points (a), (b), or (c2) that I mentioned above, or at least not in their basic configuration (but maybe you used non-standard configurations, or I just missed them in the manual, in which case please correct me). So I wouldn't say that they implement the state-of-the-art of BO. Spearmint perhaps is the package that implements most of these advanced features (although it might be lacking in other aspects, and they might be scattered in different branches).

Comment: @lacerbi the aforementioned libraries are state-of-the-art for hyperparameter optimization. Spearmint may have better optimization algorithms (though I don't know of any clear-cut benchmarks demonstrating this in papers), but it has slightly fallen out of use for hyperparameter optimization. We initially wanted to compare against Spearmint in our own benchmark, but it was agonizingly slow, so we stopped using it.

Comment: @Marc: Well, full-BO is admittedly for very costly target functions (e.g., hours or more), so I am not sure of how or what you're comparing (e.g., before I asked how many function evaluations you were considering). I suppose I'll have to wait for your paper to come out to know the details. I am very interested in knowing the full extent of efficacy of BO; I agree with you that an extensive benchmark is missing (most NIPS papers only show a few examples which you can only hope they were not cherry-picked); for this it's also important to know which flavour of BO is being considered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is problem-dependent and cannot be given without additional context. 
Typically, the answer would go as follows. Bayesian Optimization is more suitable for low-dimensional problems with the computational budget up to say 10x-100x the number of variables. PSO can be quite efficient for much larger budgets but is not state-of-the-art in its niche.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83006/discussion-on-answer-by-indiesolver-advantages-of-particle-swarm-optimization-ov).